# Trying to run Microsoft Virtual Labs online, gets stuck at "Checking ActiveX Control"

Tags: virtual-machine, activex

I'm running Win7 x64 and IE8 with all updates and patches installed. I just tried to access a few of the virtual labs (Exchange 2010, Sharepoint 2010, Forefront) but all of them are stalling at "Checking ActiveX Control" after passing all the prereqs fine.

I've tried disabling/enabling and reinstalling all the add-ons, registering the mstscax.dll, running IE as Admin, and combinations of all of these, but still no go.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying almost everything I could think of I just went and Reset my browser, the labs now seem to work.

Suppose it's not a big loss to do this but just for peace of mind it would've been nice to figure out what the underlying problem really is, especially if I encounter this issue again.